# Image won't scale after click

Tags: javascript, easeljs

Despite being a long-time developer I've never played with JavaScript libraries or any sort of graphics development.  With my son we're trying to create something interesting and are using createjs/easeljs as our vehicle of choice.

That said, we are going through a number of tutorials and can't determine why this isn't working.  The ball image does display but the on-click method code does not cause the image to scale.  The `onBallClick` method is being called so we suspect the reference is simply wrong somehow.

```
        var preload = new createjs.LoadQueue();
        var stage = new createjs.Stage("demoCanvas");

        function loadImage() {
          preload.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileComplete); 
          preload.loadFile({id:"ball", src:"assets/ball.png"});
        }
        function handleFileComplete(event) {
          document.body.appendChild(event.result);
          event.result.addEventListener("click", onBallClick)
        }
        function onBallClick(event) 
        { 
            var ballImage = preload.getResult("ball");
            var bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(ballImage);
            bitmap.scaleX = 0.5;
            stage.update();
        }
```

There are no errors in the developer console so we're trying to determine what is the correct reference to the bitmap.

We tried to do `createjs.Bitmap(event.result)` in `handleFileComplete` but `event.result` has a type of [Node] so we're not sure what to do with that but it doesn't appear useful for purposes of the `createjs.Bitmap()` statement.